# When I install `Chocolatey`, nothing happens after entering the command

Tags: windows, chocolatey

I enter the code in the command line:

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

Result.
[image]

Comment: You may get more joy on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. Then, I used PowerShell to install.
Use PowerShell method->

enter these code in admin command prompt->

```
>>powershell

>>Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

(if restricted comes then set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned)

```
>>Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned

>>Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

```
>>Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

for more reference visit here
https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation#install-using-powershell-from-cmdexe

The following image clearly illustrates you that what you have to do...

[For more REFERENCE(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDur1.png)